# Looking for the limit of a sequence

Tags: limits

How to find the limit of the sequence 
$$
\left(\frac{2}{2p+1}\right)^{1/p}
$$
as $p \to \infty$?

Is it just $1$?

Comment: @Mark: no, the limit is for $p\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: you can write your sequence (I write $n\in \mathbb N$ instead of $p$) as
$$\lim _{n\to \infty} (2^{\frac{1}{n}} (2n+1)^{-\frac{1}{n}})=\lim _{n\to \infty}(2^{\frac{1}{n}})\cdot \lim _{n\to \infty}  (2n+1)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\lim _{n\to \infty} (2^{\frac{1}{n}})\cdot \lim _{n\to \infty}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{n}\ln \left(2n+1\right)}\right)=1\cdot 1=1$$

Remember that: $$\lim _{n\to \infty}-\frac{\ln (2n+1)}{n}=0\tag{1}$$
because $-\frac{\ln (2n+1)}{n}=-\frac{2\ln \sqrt{2n+1}}{n}<2\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{n^2}}$
and being $\lim _{n\to \infty} 2\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{n^2}}=0 \implies (1)$

Comment: Note that we can extract the limit from the quotient precisely because the limits are finite (and the limit of the denominator is nonzero).

Comment: @Math1000 I totally agree with you. I hope I haven't made any mistakes. Could you add your comment in my answer please considering that it is important?

Comment: Remains to justify the limit of $(2n+1)^{1/n}$, and indeterminate form $\infty^0$. By the way, it is simpler to consider $(n+1/2)^{1/n}$ directly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Done! I hope that now is correct and more complete answer.

Comment: Your final informal justification isn't very different from the authoritative statement "the given limit converges to $1$ because we know it".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Delete then my answer?

Comment: @Sebastiano: or improve it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know how to improve it. Can you help me, please? You can edit my answer so that I can better understand your previous comment.

Comment: Prove that that limit is $0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Bound $2n+1$ from above by a multiple of $n$ to get rid of the constant. Use this to bound $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}$ from above, then show that the bound goes to $0$. There's relevant proofs on the site if you get stuck. Hence, $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}$ vanishes by the squeeze theorem, since it's positive.

Comment: @Jam Thank you for your advice. I hope to remember your suggestion. If you want you can edit my answer with serenity: you are authorized. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using L'Hospital,

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{\log(p+\frac12)}p=\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac1{p+\frac12}=0$$ and the initial limit is $1$.

Comment: Excuse me very much for this comment: the question is for a sequence. Therefore we can not apply the de l'Hôpital's rule. (+1)

Comment: @Sebastiano: the claim is true for the real function, hence also for the subsequence of naturals.

Comment: Recall that a function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$ if and only if for each increasing sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\to\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=L$.

Comment: @Math1000: you needn't invoke such a "strong" result. The convergence of $f(x)$ in the reals *is* granted. Then so is the convergence for any unbounded sequence.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just being thorough. Also I notice a typo and it is too late to edit my comment :(

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{(3p)^{1/p}}< (\dfrac{2}{2p+1})^{1/p}<$

$(\dfrac{2p+1}{2p+1})^{1/p}=1$

Take the limit.

Recall : $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} p^{1/p}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{2}{2p+1}\right)^{1/p}=\frac{2^{1/p}}{(2p+1)^{1/p}}$$

and since $2^{1/p}\to 2^0=1$ we need to consider

$$\lim_{p\to \infty}(2p+1)^{1/p} =1$$

indeed

$$\left[(2p+1)^{\frac1{2p+1}}\right]^{\frac{2p+1}p}\to 1^2 =1$$

since we need to recall the foundamental result as $x\to \infty$

$$x^\frac1x=e^{\frac{\log x}x} \to e^0=1$$

indeed by $x=e^y$ with $y\to \infty$

$$\frac{\log x}x=\frac y{e^y}\to 0$$